# Cakephp response object routing?

Tags: cakephp, routes, download, response, cakephp-2.3

I am using Cake 2.3 I have an app that allows users to add products and upload files associated with that product. I have encountered a problem with using response objects, as seen here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html

```
public function download(){
  $path = WWW_ROOT.$product['Product']['filename']; //gets the path-to-file 
  $this->response->file($path, array('download' => true, 'name' => 'Filename'));
  return $this->response; //as per the docs
}
```

And in my view:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Download', array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'download', $product['Product']['filename']));?>
```

So here is my problem: The file is situated under localhost/app/webroot/invoices/example.pdf, however, the download link of the file calls to localhost/products/sendFile/invoices/example.pdf.

When I debug $path, it gives me the correct URL to the file, so I am left to conclude that the download function messes somethings up.

I am able to access the file directly in the browser via URL of localhost/app/webroot/invoices/example.pdf.

Why is the download function not routing to the correct file URL for download? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending an extra param to the download action, but you are not doing anyting with it.

Change your download function to:

```
public function download($filename){
  //The $path is probably wrong, or did you upload the file to the webroot and not into a directory in the webroot?
  $path = WWW_ROOT.$filename; //gets the path-to-file 
  $this->response->file($path, array('download' => true, 'name' => 'Filename'));
  return $this->response; //as per the docs
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, still no luck. It still tries to go to the url instead of starting the download.

Comment: Please check your debug/error logs. You should find more information there.